# Uplift modeling and statistical significance

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, inference, causality

Is statistical significance in the difference between a control and treatment groups (aka Uplift) needed when training an uplift model?
If I have a historical test where no statistical significance was notices between the treatment and control groups, can it be used to build an Uplift and Causal Inference models?

Comment: Can you clarify what uplift modeling is? There is no tag for it, and there seems to be considerable variation as to what that means in practice.

Comment: Please see attached link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_modelling. It is type of Causal Inference modeling